# How do i set Auto-Increment to reset on mysql when all input values have been deleted in the app

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

In my laravel app database i have set the id field (which is the primary key of the table) to auto increment. Now i on the app have deleted all the inputs from the users i have created which in turn clears the values from my database, but then when i create newer values the id field continues with the increment and the app tries to load the deleted value.

i would like to know a way that i can set auto increment to set newer values to the last a number that follows the last number set by Auto Increment.

Answer (score 1):

Execute the folowing command:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

It will reset the auto increment counter.

Comment: please accept this as the answer if you're satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

When creating migration you could set the auto-increment field

```
$table->increments('id');
```

or on the migration for change

```
Schema::table('table', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id')->start_from(1)->change();
});
```